# Creating View - Firebird DB

Tags: sql, firebird

I have created a select that works perfectly, but when I try to create a view using it I get the error `must specify column name for view select expression`.

All of my columns are named.  What am I doing wrong?
This is my view code:

```
create view v_dj_milestone as
       select j.job_number as jobnumber,
              j.supervisor as supervisor,
              s.activity_name as stage,
              sc.proj_end_date as scheduledclose,
              sc.base_start_date as baselinestart,
              substr (j.job_number, 1, 3) as Studio,
              case substr (j.job_number, 1, 3)
                   when '001' then 'Triad'
                   when '002' then 'Triad'
                   when '003' then 'Triad'  
                   when '004' then 'Triad'
                   when '005' then 'Triangle'
                   when '006' then 'Triangle'
                   when '007' then 'Triangle'
                   when '008' then 'Triangle'
                   when '009' then 'Charlotte'
                   when '010' then 'Charlotte'
                   when '011' then 'Charlotte'
                   when '012' then 'Charlotte'
                   when '013' then 'Charlotte'
                   when '014' then 'Florida'
                   when '015' then 'Florida'
                   when '017' then 'Florida'
                   when '023' then 'Costal Carolina'
                   when '024' then  'Costal Carolina'
                   when '025' then  'Costal Carolina'
                   else 'Unknown'
                         end as DIV,
            (sc.proj_end_date - sc.base_start_date) as Days,
            (sc.base_calduration - (sc.proj_end_date - sc.base_start_date)) as Variance,
            (sc.base_calduration / (sc.proj_end_date - sc.base_start_date))*100 as Accuracy
      from job j
           inner join cutoff_phase c
                 on (j.cutoff_phase_ID = c.cutoff_phase_id)
           inner join sactivity s
                 on (c.sactivity_id = s.sactivity_id)
           inner join schedule sc
                 on (sc.job_number = j.job_number);
```

Comment: Which Firebird version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

For me, `in VIEW`, you can't use alias name in view body.

Try this:

```
create view v_dj_milestone (jobnumber, supervisor, stage, scheduledclose, baselinestart, Studio, DIV, Days, Variance, Accuracy) as
       select j.job_number,
              j.supervisor,
              s.activity_name,
              sc.proj_end_date,
              sc.base_start_date,
              substr (j.job_number, 1, 3),
              case substr (j.job_number, 1, 3)
                   when '001' then 'Triad'
                   when '002' then 'Triad'
                   when '003' then 'Triad'  
                   when '004' then 'Triad'
                   when '005' then 'Triangle'
                   when '006' then 'Triangle'
                   when '007' then 'Triangle'
                   when '008' then 'Triangle'
                   when '009' then 'Charlotte'
                   when '010' then 'Charlotte'
                   when '011' then 'Charlotte'
                   when '012' then 'Charlotte'
                   when '013' then 'Charlotte'
                   when '014' then 'Florida'
                   when '015' then 'Florida'
                   when '017' then 'Florida'
                   when '023' then 'Costal Carolina'
                   when '024' then  'Costal Carolina'
                   when '025' then  'Costal Carolina'
                   else 'Unknown'
                         end,
            (sc.proj_end_date - sc.base_start_date),
            (sc.base_calduration - (sc.proj_end_date - sc.base_start_date)),
            (sc.base_calduration / (sc.proj_end_date - sc.base_start_date))*100
      from job j
           inner join cutoff_phase c
                 on (j.cutoff_phase_ID = c.cutoff_phase_id)
           inner join sactivity s
                 on (c.sactivity_id = s.sactivity_id)
           inner join schedule sc
                 on (sc.job_number = j.job_number);
```

Comment: I use MSSQL :). I'm not sure for other DBMS

Comment: Very weird. Ran this code and got an error that says 'metadata cannot be updated, table v_dj_milestone already exists?

The code is creating a view, not a table and there is no table or view named v_dj_milestone?

Comment: you can drop exists view :)

Comment: @DavidJustice A view is a 'virtual' table, Firebird currently doesn't make the distinction between a real table and a view in this error message.

Answer (score 0):

you must coding as

```
create view v_dj_milestone (jobnumber,supervisor, .. .. jName ) as
       select j.job_number as jobnumber,
              j.supervisor as supervisor,
              s.activity_name as stage,
              sc.proj_end_date as scheduledclose,
              sc.base_start_date as baselinestart,
              substr (j.job_number, 1, 3) as Studio,      
                case substr (j.job_number, 1, 3)
               when '001' then 'Triad'
               when '002' then 'Triad'
               when '003' then 'Triad'  
               when '004' then 'Triad'
               when '005' then 'Triangle'
               when '006' then 'Triangle'
               when '007' then 'Triangle'
               when '008' then 'Triangle'
               when '009' then 'Charlotte'
               when '010' then 'Charlotte'
               when '011' then 'Charlotte'
               when '012' then 'Charlotte'
               when '013' then 'Charlotte'
               when '014' then 'Florida'
               when '015' then 'Florida'
               when '017' then 'Florida'
               when '023' then 'Costal Carolina'
               when '024' then  'Costal Carolina'
               when '025' then  'Costal Carolina'
               else 'Unknown'
                     end as jName,
```

Comment: Listing the column names is not required